# "A namespace doesnot containmembers such as fields or methods" for Stylesheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio

I am trying to build a web app project using C#. and i am getting the error message "A namespace doesnot containmembers such as fields or methods". Error Code 7. and file name is my CSS file that it is showing with Row number and column no. 1. I am using Visual Studio 2008, and the first class created(body) is blue underlined. I have checked the web.config file and it its build action is set to "none"

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have checked the web.config file and it its build action is set to "none"`
Why do you check the web.config to see what the build action of the .css file is? You should use the properties dialog? The build action for the web.config is Content aswell.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your file extension is .CSS and not .CS?  If so, rename the file with a .css extension and try again.

Comment: yeah..i m sure it is .css and not .cs

Answer (score 1):

Change the build action to Content? Does it have .css as the extension?

Comment: Yes. It does have .css file extension. I have even tried changing build action to content. but then, the system gives error on aspx pages asking for identifier '}'

Comment: I think it would really help if you could post a screenshot of your solution explorer and the code inside the css file. I am stumped at the moment :-)